# need help writing command in unix terminal with regular expression

Tags: regex, unix, terminal

I have to write a command to extract a jar file for a specific module in the project. In the project we have multiple modules including following modules

- core-10.10.jar
- core-support-10.10.jar
- core-server-10.10.jar

I want to extract only core-10.10.jar. But our version number change every month. So, I want to write something like

```
jar xf core-[0-9]*.*.jar
```

Can someone help me write correct "jar xf" command?

Comment: Should work, but what's problem?

Comment: Oh yeah. It works. Sorry, I had not tried the script myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
jar xf core-[0-9]*.*.jar
```

This actually works. Sorry, I had not tried it before asking this question.